# pandas - merging multiple DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

This is a multi-part question.  I just can't seem to combine everything together.  The goal is to to create one DataFrame (guessing using MultiIndex) that I can access as follows:

```
ticker = 'GOLD'
date = pd.to_datetime('1978/03/31')
current_bar = df.ix[ticker].ix[date]
```

Can I then just say:  current_bar.Last ?

Anyway, here are the files, and how I load them.

```
In [108]: df = pd.read_csv('GOLD.csv', parse_dates='Date', index_col='Date')
In [109]: df
Out[109]: 
            Exp       Last     Volume
Date
1978-03-30  198002    995.6    54
1978-03-31  198002    999.5    78

In [110]: df2 = pd.read_csv('SPX.csv', parse_dates='Date', index_col='Date')
In [111]: df2
Out[111]: 
            Exp       Last     Volume
Date
1978-03-30  198003    215.5    25
1978-03-31  198003    214.1    99
```

Ideally, I want it to look like this (I think):

```
ticker      GOLD                            SPX
values      Exp       Last     Volume       Exp       Last     Volume
Date
1978-03-30  198002    995.6    54           198003    215.5    25
1978-03-31  198002    999.5    78           198003    214.1    99
```

1. I guess my questions are:

   - How do I make this Hierarchical  (the actual data has 20+ identical columns for each file)
   - How do I then combine the files (I have about 100 that need to all go in 1 DataFrame)
   - Is my assumption correct that I can then just do: current_bar.Last to get values?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `pd.concat` to *concatenate* DataFrames. (*Concatenating* smushes DataFrames together, while *merging* joins DataFrames based on common indices or columns). When you supply the `keys` parameter, you get a hierarchical index:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('GOLD.csv', parse_dates='Date', index_col='Date', sep='\s+')
df2 = pd.read_csv('SPX.csv', parse_dates='Date', index_col='Date', sep='\s+')
result = pd.concat([df, df2], keys=['GOLD', 'SPX'], names=['ticker']).unstack('ticker')
result = result.reorder_levels([1, 0], axis=1).sortlevel(level=0, axis=1)
print(result)
```

yields

```
ticker        GOLD                    SPX               
               Exp   Last  Volume     Exp   Last  Volume
Date                                                    
1978-03-30  198002  995.6      54  198003  215.5      25
1978-03-31  198002  999.5      78  198003  214.1      99
```

`result['Last']` yields the DataFrame:

```
In [147]: result['Last']
Out[147]: 
ticker       GOLD    SPX
Date                    
1978-03-30  995.6  215.5
1978-03-31  999.5  214.1
```

I'd recommend avoiding the syntax `result.Last` because it is too close to `result.last`, which returns a DataFrame method.

---

To handle more files, you might use code like this:

```
import pandas as pd
dfs = list()
for filename in filenames:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, parse_dates='Date', index_col='Date')
    # compute moving_mean
    dfs.append(df)

keys = [filename[:-4] for filename in filenames]
result = pd.concat(dfs, keys=keys, names=['ticker']).unstack('ticker')
```

Note that this does require enough memory to hold a list of all the DataFrames in memory plus enough memory to hold `result`.

Comment: Got it.  What if I want to add another df to 'result' (ie 'NDX').  what would I use for the keys, given that result already has 2?  (I just need to do this for 100 files, so need a way to do it iteratively.  Thanks

Comment: The first argument to `pd.concat` can be a list of 100 DataFrames, and `keys` can be a list of 100 ticker names. For example, to concatenate 3 DataFrames: `result = pd.concat([df, df2, df3], keys=['GOLD', 'SPX', 'NDX'], names=['ticker']).unstack('ticker')`

Comment: Is there a way to do something like this:  result = pd.concat([result, df3], keys =[result.keys, 'NDX'], names=['ticker']).unstack('ticker')?

Comment: The reason for my above question is that I need to perform some functions (moving_mean) on the files before adding them to the 'result' df.  As far as I know I can't do those when in MultiIndex, correct?

Comment: I've edited the code (above) to show how you might compute the moving_mean before concatening.