# Pandas: merge multiple dataframes and control column names?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to merge nine Pandas dataframes together into a single dataframe, doing a join on two columns, controlling the column names. Is this possible?

I have nine datasets. All of them have the following columns:

```
org, name, items,spend
```

I want to join them into a single dataframe with the following columns:

```
org, name, items_df1, spend_df1, items_df2, spend_df2, items_df3...
```

I've been reading the documentation on [merging and joining](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html). I can currently merge two datasets together like this:

```
ad = pd.DataFrame.merge(df_presents, df_trees,
                        on=['practice', 'name'],
                        suffixes=['_presents', '_trees'])
```

This works great, doing `print list(aggregate_data.columns.values)` shows me the following columns:

```
[org', u'name', u'spend_presents', u'items_presents', u'spend_trees', u'items_trees'...]
```

But how can I do this for nine columns? `merge` only seems to accept two at a time, and if I do it sequentially, my column names are going to end up very messy.

Comment: Just found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853762/pandas-merging-multiple-dataframes but I'm not sure it works for my example - I guess I need to concatenate, then merge somehow? I want to write my output to a BigQuery table, so I don't know if hierarchical dataframes will work for me.

Comment: Found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668427/pandas-joining-multiple-dataframes-on-columns?rq=1 which is more promising, but doesn't explain how to control the column names.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) to iteratively apply `pd.merge` to each of the DataFrames:

```
result = functools.reduce(merge, dfs)
```

This is equivalent to

```
result = dfs[0]
for df in dfs[1:]:
    result = merge(result, df)
```

To pass the `on=['org', 'name']` argument, you could use `functools.partial` define the merge function:

```
merge = functools.partial(pd.merge, on=['org', 'name'])
```

Since specifying the `suffixes` parameter in `functools.partial` would only allow
one fixed choice of suffix, and since here we need a different suffix for each
`pd.merge` call, I think it would be easiest to prepare the DataFrames column
names before calling `pd.merge`:

```
for i, df in enumerate(dfs, start=1):
    df.rename(columns={col:'{}_df{}'.format(col, i) for col in ('items', 'spend')}, 
              inplace=True)
```

---

For example,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import functools
np.random.seed(2015)

N = 50
dfs = [pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(5, size=(N,4)), 
                    columns=['org', 'name', 'items', 'spend']) for i in range(9)]
for i, df in enumerate(dfs, start=1):
    df.rename(columns={col:'{}_df{}'.format(col, i) for col in ('items', 'spend')}, 
              inplace=True)
merge = functools.partial(pd.merge, on=['org', 'name'])
result = functools.reduce(merge, dfs)
print(result.head())
```

yields

```
   org  name  items_df1  spend_df1  items_df2  spend_df2  items_df3  \
0    2     4          4          2          3          0          1   
1    2     4          4          2          3          0          1   
2    2     4          4          2          3          0          1   
3    2     4          4          2          3          0          1   
4    2     4          4          2          3          0          1   

   spend_df3  items_df4  spend_df4  items_df5  spend_df5  items_df6  \
0          3          1          0          1          0          4   
1          3          1          0          1          0          4   
2          3          1          0          1          0          4   
3          3          1          0          1          0          4   
4          3          1          0          1          0          4   

   spend_df6  items_df7  spend_df7  items_df8  spend_df8  items_df9  spend_df9  
0          3          4          1          3          0          1          2  
1          3          4          1          3          0          0          3  
2          3          4          1          3          0          0          0  
3          3          3          1          3          0          1          2  
4          3          3          1          3          0          0          3
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you very much! It unfortunately is an inner join however, how would you deal with an outer join?

Comment: @jeangelj: You can add `how='outer'` to the `functools.partial` call: e.g. `merge = functools.partial(pd.merge, on=['org', 'name'], how='outer')`.

Answer (score 0):

Would doing a big `pd.concat()` and then renaming all the columns work for you?  Something like:

```
desired_columns = ['items', 'spend']
big_df = pd.concat([df1, df2[desired_columns], ..., dfN[desired_columns]], axis=1)


new_columns = ['org', 'name']
for i in range(num_dataframes):
    new_columns.extend(['spend_df%i' % i, 'items_df%i' % i])

bid_df.columns = new_columns
```

This should give you columns like:

`org, name, spend_df0, items_df0, spend_df1, items_df1, ..., spend_df8, items_df8`

Answer (score 0):

I've wanted this as well at times but been unable to find a built-in pandas way of doing it. Here is my suggestion (and my plan for the next time I need it):

1. Create an empty dictionary, `merge_dict`.
2. Loop through the index you want for each of your data frames and add the desired values to the dictionary with the index as the key.
3. Generate a new index as `sorted(merge_dict)`.
4. Generate a new list of data for each column by looping through merge_dict.items().
5. Create a new data frame with `index=sorted(merge_dict)` and columns created in the previous step.

Basically, this is somewhat like a hash join in SQL. Seems like the most efficient way I can think of and shouldn't take too long to code up.

Good luck.